# What does trusting the service `ec2.amazonaws.com` permit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, identity-management

Suppose I have the following IAM Trust Policy (written in Terraform):

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_trust_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
 }

resource "aws_iam_role" "my_iam_role" {
  name = "my_iam_role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.my_trust_policy.json
}
```

Does this effectively allow *any* EC2 instance to assume this role, and any permissions attached to this role?

Comment: Not by default, you have attach this IAM role to an EC2 first. 

Comment: No, it's a trust policy that allows the EC2 service, on your behalf, to assume the given IAM role. That's how an EC2 instance, launched with this role, gets (temporary, auto-rotated) AWS credentials with the permissions declared in the role.

Answer (score 0):

Trust policy in AWS defines who can assume the role. In your case, you allow the EC2 service to assume that role, but the EC2 instance cannot assume the role on its own. What is actually happening here is that this trust policy allows you to attach a role to the EC2 instance (as an instance profile).